# Identifying and executing variables

Tags: c++

I'm extremely new to C++ (I only started the course on it about 3 weeks ago) and I don't understand why this small program I'm trying to execute won't run. Here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int A;
    int Y;
    A = 5;
    Y = 1;
    cout << Y = ++A << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I've tried writing it outside the block and I get back the error "invalid operands of types 'int' and '' to binary operator<<'. I've also tried declaring and initializing it in the same line and the same result. I'm really lost I've experimented for the last hour and no breakthroughs.

Comment: Operator precedence.

Comment: So should I instead write '++A = Y' ?

Comment: @SpongeAssassin No. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Comment: @SpongeAssassin Your nick sounds like you want to troll people here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ῥεῖ No it's just what I've commonly used in online environments

Comment: @SpongeAssassin /OT So you're a spongebob hater? ;-)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, he is executing variables. Exactly the sort of thing one would expect an assassin to do with variables.

Comment: @user4581301 You seem to be right. Variables are terrorists, they deserve execution :-P ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the equal sign, aka the assignment operator in your `cout` line. Take that out.

```
cout << Y << " " << ++A << endl;
```

Also for future note when asking StackOverflow questions please tell us what you are trying to do and what you expect to happen.

Describing what your code is supposed to do is also a major point of [TDD (Test Driven Development)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) which you should learn early on because it is so effective and useful.

Comment: Okay thank you. And thanks for the advice on asking questions, it is my first time on here. Appreciate the help